# Sublime Text 3 File Browser Shows /* Next to JS and CSS Files - What is this?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I've noticed that JS and CSS files in the Sublime Text 3 file browser sidebar show `/*` next to them. What is this? Does this represent something specific? It appears as though it only shows on JS and CSS files. I'm assuming this is supposed to be some sort of file type icon, but I'd like to know if it actually means something. I do use the [SidebarEnhancements](https://github.com/SideBarEnhancements-org/SideBarEnhancements) package.

[image]

Comment: if you create a .htm/.html file, does it have the same icon?

Comment: It does not have the same icon. It adds `< >` for the icon. Its confusing because each file type appears to have its own icon, except for JS and CSS files which share the opening comment characters `/*`.

Comment: Do all your css and js files start with a header comment?

Comment: They do not all start, or even contain comments.

Comment: then its just the developers choice. the why of it will likely never be known. I had a project a couple years ago, where I had to use bootstrap glyphs for filetype iconography. since there are only so many glyphs, I had to choose where to use each one, so PDFs, Word Docs, and Excel spreadsheets all ended up with the same icon. you just work with what you have, and icons usually cost money, since most programmers are not graphic designers.